# How to set database.yml conditions for each OS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, yaml

I would like to set sprocket in Linux and Windows. Both in my database.yml, how to?

Now:

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
database: skeletor_dev
pool: 25
username: root
password: 
socket: /private/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I want something like:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: skeletor_dev
  pool: 25
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /private/var/mysql/mysql.sock if os => windows
  socket: /private/var/mysql/mysql.sock if os => linux
```

Is it possible? How to?

Comment: you can do multiple environments like `development_windows:` and `development_linux` and define socket as per wise `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development_windows`

Comment: This is not, what I want...

Answer (score 0):

Use ERB.

```
development:
  socket: <%= %w[windows linux].include?(ruby_code_to_get_os) ? '/path/to/sock' : nil %>
```

Obviously you'll have to figure out how to best determine the platform itself, but that should get you going.